# How to have a left/right scrollbar in Windows 10 command prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd

I wonder if it is possible to have, toghether with the up/down scrollbar, a left/right scrollbar in Windows 10 command prompt, since with long lines I am not able to see the end of the line.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

The default Windows' `cmd` layout settings do not have the horizontal scrollbar enabled since the **Screen buffer size** width is the same as the **Window size** width

[image: cmd layout default settings]

To enable the horizontal scrollbar, change the **Screen buffer size** width to be more than the **Window size** width, e.g., change it to `800` instead of `80` and you should notice that the horizontal scrollbar appeared.

Alternatively, you can use Windows' Powershell, or consider using an alternative Windows terminal like [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/).

Comment: Incorrect. My `cmd` windows automatically adds horizontal scroll bars if I change the width to be less than the longest line.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill for the information, I did not know that before. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need set the columns/lines:

```
mode con: cols=120 lines=10

rem :: or...

mode 120,10
```

This set to columns 120 and lines 10

---

From [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/mode.html)

---

```
Display size/buffer - number of columns wide and number of lines deep:
      MODE CON[:] [COLS=c] [LINES=n]

   (undocumented) abbreviated version of the above:
      MODE Cols, Lines
```

---