Maximum capacity of 157 characters to be printed on the screen when printing something in C
I've been encountering this problem where the program automatically breaks lines after it reaches 157 characters in screen. For example. When I run this program
int main(void){
    for (int i = 0; i < 158; i++){
        printf("*");
    }
    return 0;
}

It prints 157 "*" in the same line. When it reaches the 158th "*", the program automatically breaks a line when I haven't written a "\n" anywhere in this program. Is this a "quirk" of the programming language/compiler itself? If so, how and why does it happen? And also can you recommend me some ways to circumvent this issue and possibly recommend some resources to lean and understand a bit similar "quirks" of the language and where they stem from.

I have 158 "*" in one line, so the code is good. Maybe this behavior come from the terminal ? How much column does your terminal have ?

What are your terminal settings? What is the size of the terminal window?

Your program doesn't break any lines. Your terminal does, so that all output is visible. There is nothing to learn or circumvent here. Leave it as is.

If you have a linux console: Type stty -a and see the first line to get the terminal width (columns).

Change the width of the terminal window (make it smaller) and try again.

@tom's  Currently it shows 120(width)x30(height).

@wiimm Am currently using Dev C++'s Terminal

@wimm i tried lowering/updating the width of the terminal through the property of the DEV C++'s terminal multiple times but it keeps resetting the width to 157 for some reason :/

if you printf("mmmmmmmmmm\niiiiiiiiii\n"); do the two output lines have the same length (monospace font)? Or is the line with ms longer (proportional font)? C kinda assumes a monospace font for output, but will work with any font (maybe with tables or other alignment off)

^^^ what he said.

The OP wrote that they are not studying computer science or anything related. So, let me guess: the OP is an arts major, so the first thing they did with their terminal was, of course, to choose a very good looking proportional font!   (-:=

Well, Dev-C++ is rather old and unmaintained, and comes with a very of compiler version as well. It may have a number of bugs or other problems that will never be fixed. There are many other free environments available that are modern and up to date.

@pmg they have have the same size

@mikenakis About to get into a pure mathematics program actually. I come from rural part of the world so don't really know very much about tech and computers. I really just set this IDE up like how youtube told me to and read the manual made for the GNU compiler. SO yeah, simple problem like these are a nuisance and cause problems though I am trying find my way and learn/understand through this unfamiliar subject

@tyivern I tried to make a funny guess.  Good luck and success with your endeavor!

@someprogrammerdude what IDE would you recommend? I tried running VS code but it ran really slow on my computer as I have a very cheap computer that I bought second hand which has like 4 gigs of ram and a very old processor and Im trying to get the best out of it

@mikenakis you too man good luck :D

You wrote Currently it shows 120(width) and also it keeps resetting the width to 157; how does this go together?

@armali every time I change the width to something like 127 and re-run the program the width of the terminal keeps getting reset to it's value of 157

Learning C is a Journey, not a Race. It will take time and a good book (yes book). To that end, drop by The Definitive C Book Guide and List. You learn C the same way you eat a whale -- one byte at a time. Good luck with your coding :) IDE? Any old text editor (preferably one with syntax highlighting) and a command line is what you need to learn to write and compile C. IDE's are nice -- but usually have a learning curve all their own that confuses new programmers. An editor and terminal is all you need.

Just leave it alone. It's not worth your time. You can redirect the output to a file and then open the file with a text editor. Then you won't see any line wrap (if you set up the editor not to wrap lines).

Also what OS and What terminal. If Windows, then program exit automatically adds a newline if I recall correctly. (and that's not C doing it, it's windows -- your code outputs no new line -- but to be POSIX compliant -- it should)

@DavidC.Rankin Will Certainly will do! I am currently using Richard Reese's- Understanding and using pointers after I finished reading the GNU C manual which was very very helpful.
I am using windows 10-Enterprise edition as the OS, Also I used both the DEV C++ terminal which shows up when you execute the program and also the "cmd" terminal where I also ran the program manually. Both had this issue where it kept breaking lines after the 157th *.

Are you sure you want to start with C? I'd never recommend it as the first language to study, as it forces you to worry about low-level things that are trivial in other languages. Even using strings isn't simple in C! I suggest to start from another language. Popular choices would be Python, Java and C#.

You might like this question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207227/how-to-have-a-left-right-scrollbar-in-windows-10-command-prompt

@pmg Yes, I tried that. I Increased/Decreased the width of the terminal but it just keeps getting set back to 157 ,120, 152 again and again

@FabiosaysReinstateMonica - I kind of take the other view. I would highly recommend starting with C. It embodies the discipline you must develop to be a successful coder. It demands you pay attention to every byte of your memory use and it is standards based where the man-pages do a good job of tracking the standard. There are no training-wheels with C. It gives you the power to do everything a computer can do and it places the responsibility to use the language correctly on the user. There is no nanny auto memory management in the background. Learn C and write better code in all languages.

@FabiosaysReinstateMonica yes. I feel like I'm already invested in this as I've really already went out of my way to buy a book on pointers, which I'm already about to finish. I'll have to go and invest in other resources to study from which is kind of a big investment for me. I do not have good access to information easily as of yet and am solely relying on free information. Also, If it's easy to understand and abstracts a lot of stuff then I feel like you're not learning enough to have a good understanding on the subject you know and Consequently I wanna learn as much as I possibly can.

What do you mean by it just keeps getting set back to 157 ,120, 152 again and again? How and in which time intervals do you see that the cmd window is getting set to several widths?

Dev C++ is a bit dated. He is talking about the terminal Dev C++ pops up to provide output on stdout and stderr. It is also that console that is automatically adding the newline on program exit. If you are on windows, unless you are using the VisualStudio Community Edition (with it's "Developer's Command Prompt" -- which is good), I would recommend using the MSys2 environment with MinGW. It is a fantastic Linux development environment which provides a great terminal, and you can tweak the setup (.bashrc, environment variables, etc..) just as you would a Linux box. Quite good!

@DavidC.Rankin Thank you for the info! will definitely try it

@Armali right after I run the exe file in the cmd terminal or when I click on the terminal window of dev c-c++

There is a great benefit to MSys2 as well -- it uses Archlinux's pacman package manager - that is simple and fast. Like Archlinux, MSys2 provides cutting-edge current releases of gcc and all of the associated tools. Currently gcc-14. I've used Msys2 for regular desktop development (both windows and Linux) and for embedded system development for Raspberry Pi Pico as well. Very flexible, and also has all the nice Linux tools, vim, ssh, rsync, curl, sed, awk, and just about any library you can think of. It takes a bit of learning -- but well worth it.

If you install MSys2, don't forget the Archlinux wiki pacman. That will tell you all you need to know in a 10 minute read to be able to install, update, remove packages in the MSys2 environment with pacman. Good luck!

@DavidC.Rankin tried to download msys2 & install it but apparently the installer only compatible for 64 bit computer and mine is a 32-bit which is a shame :(

Your answer right after I run the exe file in the cmd terminal still doesn't tell me how you can perceive that the window is getting set to multiple different widths 157 ,120, 152 at the time.

@armali ahh okay, I think I'll skip off from this topic for now and come back to it later in time

@tyivern - oh.. Yes, it's 64-bit. Other Linux option is a Pi Zero 2 W -- gives you a full Linux OS :). Depending on your drive-space, VisualStudio Community edition is free and what you really care about for learning is the "Developer's Command Prompt" which gives you a good terminal and you can compile with the default MS compiler (cl.exe) or also install the 32-bit MinGW and have gcc available too. Or, just install WSL and have your Linux as part of windows. Or do both. Once your projects get more complex and you learn grep, sed & awk, you may find Linux has benefits :)

@DavidC.Rankin For sure, I think I'll give Visual Studio a try again and switch over to WSL if things don't go so well in my pc in a later date. I don't really have much experience on operating systems and I'm afraid I'll break something If I start messing with operating systems right now.  Thanks for the guidelines and suggestions will definitely give it a go :)

There's a trick, spend $35 on a 256G SSD and install the 2nd OS to that. You just remove (or unplug) your current drive, install the new, put the USB drive with the installer in and boot and follow the install procedure. If it all goes south, just unplug the new SSD and plug your old drive back in and you can try again later :)

Short answer:
your code is working correctly and it prints 158 * in one line, The issue you’re seeing, where the line seems to break after 157 characters, is actually because of the settings of your terminal or console. Most terminals automatically wrap long lines to make them fit within the visible screen area. for readability only, This is not a problem with your code or the C language itself, but rather a feature of the terminal you’re using.
More explanation:
if you want to test this better try to write in a text file instead of a terminal, this will help you to see the exact character written in the file, and that will help you to see the Unicode of it.
try this code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *file = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 158; i++) {
        fprintf(file, "*");
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

after running this code you will notice a file named as output.txt created with the 158 * in one line, try to open it using the text editor, then try to open it using hex readers.
What are hex editors?
it is a program that shows you the binary or hex data of the file, which means it will show you each byte value, and since the char in c lang = 1 byte, so each byte means one character, in other words, each byte is one *.
in a hex editor you will see something like this photo:

as you can see in the photo there are so many 2A, according to the ASCII code * = 42, 42 in decimal = 2A in hexadecimal, in other words, 2A is the *.

While your answer is generally true, why do you make it so complicated? You could just use the original program, redirect the output to a text file and open in a text editor. There you don't need to know that 2A is '*', as there a '*' is just a '*' and if you don't see any line breaks, in the file, there aren't any.

@Gerhardh Yes I already said that here: ("after running this code you will notice a file named as output.txt created with the 158 * in one line, try to open it using the text editor"), but if he wants to dive even deeper, he can open it using a hex editor.

Well, imagine you could make it happen. Imagine the 158th star would print right next tot he 157th.
Would it be off screen? Maybe just out of the terminal window, under the vertical scroll bar?
Or is there space after the 157th star for more of them?
With some work it is possible to make it print on and on to the right and keep the information available using the horizontal scrollbar, but it depends on a lot of things: your terminal, your Operating System to name a few.
Just take advantage of the system as it is, knowing it will not hide information from you -- but it may make long lines ugly.
In my experience, line wrapping (what is hapenning to you now) is better than horizontal scrolling. But I'm used to the command line and most things I use keep the information within the first 80 columns so it always looks nice.
If you really really want to see the output without line wrapping and without trying to make horizontal scrolling available in your terminal, try and output to a file and after that look at the file with a text editor (which has horizontal scrolling built in by default).
Two ways to output to a file:
a) using Windows command redirection (when you're comfortable using the command-line) and no change to your code
b) changing your code
How to change your code:
#include <stdio.h> // fopen(), fclose(), perror(), fprintf()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "w"); // will use test.txt for output
    if (f == NULL) {                  // error detected
        perror("test.txt");           // report error
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);           // and exit
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 158; i++) {
        fprintf(f, "*");              // output to file
    }
    fprintf(f, "\n");                 // add a final line terminator
    fclose(f);                        // properly close the file
}

After you compile and run the program above, you should have a new "test.txt" file in your folder.

"Would it be off screen? Maybe just out of the terminal window, under the vertical scroll bar? Or is there space after the 157th star for more of them?". I'd want it to be the space after the 157th star, So that I can use the horizontal scroll in the terminal to see the information. I have created a (budget)Spreadsheet which is not coded nicely but This whole problem of this printing * next has arose cause I couldn't print the cells right next to each other when a certain amount of row was inputted. There seems to be a character limit here, do you know anywhere else I can post the code?

I still think your best bet is using an intermediate text file. Anyway check out online compilers: some do what you want, eg: https://onecompiler.com/c/42qdp2ah3

I see thank you for the information, Here's the Code https://onecompiler.com/c/42qdpgj9u
If you were to input certain Rows Here, The program will go crazy and just start printing the top line of the row after line breaking it destroying the program

You're not using anything with a prototype in <conio.h>, or <stdlib.h>, or <math.h>. I've removed those headers from your source. Your function declarations at the top should really be prototypes. I changed them too. You called the functions with the wrong parameters in a few places; also attempted to correct that. IMPORTANT you're using the array pass with invalid data. Check my changes (including formatting, sorry) and comments: https://onecompiler.com/c/42qdrnbsz

Thank you for the help and also pointing out my mistakes. Also I'm kind of confused with passing the array pass as uninitialized. By uninitialized do you mean I didn't assign a value to the array or it's not able to allocate memory cause it has no definite value? I'm quite confused as feel like I have defined above variables at the appropriate time for the array to determine how much memory it should allocate to store data.

Not initialized as in without a value. The array has enough space for the rows and columns specified, but you use it before setting all elements. See https://onecompiler.com/c/42qdtv6f8

ahh I see thank you for info and the help

Your answer I'd want it to be the space after the 157th star, So that I can use the horizontal scroll in the terminal to see the information confuses me. If there were space after the 157th star, you would see the character in that space without having to scroll, wouldn't you?

@Armali Ok so when I zoom out from the program there's still space in the terminal that goes on wards left, but the program itself doesn't go onward from the 157th character but instead breaks the line. There's like this invisible wall around the output of the program and every time it hits that wall it automatically breaks line. I can say this as every program when i run from the terminal prints out
"--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.1817 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . ."
even this "-----" perforation gets stuck and ends in that "wall"

I simply don't want my printed info to hit that wall and get printed out on the next line

When you say every program when i run from the terminal prints out "-------------------------------- Process exited after … you are talking about Dev C++'s terminal, not cmd, right? You wrote that the cmd terminal is set to some width when you run the program; but this isn't the case if you run e. g. echo with a greater number of characters, is it?

The line break you're seeing is due to the terminal's line wrapping, not a quirk of C. To avoid it, you can adjust your terminal settings or format your output explicitly in your code.
int main(void){
    for(int i=0; i<158; i++){
        printf("*");
        if ((i+1) % 157 == 0) {
            printf("\n"); // Print a newline after every 157 characters
        }
    }
}


Welcome to SO. The OP asks how to circumwent the line breaks. Adding them explicitely is quite the opposite.
